# I can't get PHP file extension for videos and audio

Tags: php

I have a page to upload video image and music files.
I can upload the image files with no problem, but when I choose to upload video or music files the code can't even recognize the file extension.
This code work fine in Windows but when I move this code to CentOS 6.3 this code don't work for the video or music files.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $usern = $_SESSION['username'];
    $fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"];
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"];
    $fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"];
    $fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"];
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"];
    $path = $_FILES['file1']['type'];
    $ext = substr($path, strrpos($filename, '.') + 6);

    if ($ext == 'png' || $ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'gif') {
        if (!$fileTmpLoc) {
            echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button";
            exit();
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "usersdata/$usern/images/$fileName")) {
            mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '1') or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db('cloud') or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO images VALUES('','$fileName','usersdata/$usern/images/$fileName','$usern')");

            if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
                echo "upload is complete";
            }

        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
        }

    } else if ($ext == '.mp4' || $ext == 'avi' || $ext == 'flv') {
        if (!$fileTmpLoc) {
            echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button";
            exit();
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "usersdata/$usern/video/$fileName")) {
            mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '1') or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db('cloud') or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO video VALUES('','$fileName','usersdata/$usern/video/$fileName','$usern')");

            if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
                echo "upload is complete";
            }

        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
        }

    } else if ($ext == 'mpeg') {
        if (!$fileTmpLoc) {
            echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button";
            exit();
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "usersdata/$usern/musics/$fileName")) {
            mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '1') or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db('cloud') or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO musics VALUES('','$fileName','usersdata/$usern/musics/$fileName','$usern')");

            if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
                echo "upload is complete";
            }

        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
        }

    } else {
        echo "The Type You Are Tring To upload not Supported";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What file extensions are causing a problem?

Comment: What error(s) do you get? Why is one of the extensions you check `.mp4` and all other without the `.`?

Comment: Don't use file extensions to determine the type of file someone has uploaded; they can call it whatever they like. You should be using a function which looks at the contents of the file.

Comment: no error but it go to the The Type You Are Tring To upload not Supported in case of video or audio files

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't rely on strrpos to extract the file extension.  You should be using [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) instead.
2. You need to compare file extensions in a case-insensitive manner.  As it stands, your script will match ".jpg", but not ".JPG" as a valid extension.
3. Instead of using lots of OR clauses, store the valid extensions in an array and use [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to search it.

**For example:**

```
$image_ext_list = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'gif');
$video_ext_list = array('avi', 'mp4', 'mkv', 'flv');
$file_path = '/example/file/path/image.jpg';

// Extract the path parts to get the file extension.
// If there is no extension, $path_parts['extension'] will be null.
$path_parts = pathinfo($file_path);
$file_ext = isset($path_parts['extension']) ? $path_parts['extension'] : '';

// Convert the file extension to lower-case so it's not case sensitive.
$file_ext = strtolower($file_ext);

// Check if the extension is in the list of image extensions
if (in_array($file_ext, $image_ext_list)) {
    // Uploaded file is an image

} elseif (in_array($file_ext, $video_ext_list)) {
    // Uploaded file is a video

} else {
    // Uploaded file extension isn't in list
}
```

Comment: Or, even better than `in_array`, an associative array with extensions as keys, and types as values.

Comment: Good explanation but I don't think this answers OPs question.

Comment: thanks for your advice man i'll update my code ,, but in linux i cant even access the video or audio files info ,,

Comment: @ArvinSloane are you sure you got the proper permissions to read those files ?

Comment: @Kei - You don't need to be able to *read* a file to check it's extension.  You only need to be able to *see* it (more specifically, the directory it's in).

Comment: @Mr.Llama yeah, sorry for expressing that badly, I meant "do you have permissions to see them?"